# Internet sometimes randomly pops out and won't work anymore (Except some pages)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, firewall

My internet connections sometimes drops randomly, and can only be fixed by restarting. When it drops, I notice a lot of `ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED` errors and not working connections. The weird part is that some websites (E.g. Google (always) and some other still function correctly), sometimes without the CSS (the style). Localhost seems to be down too (???) on both Wamp and Xampp. I tried to investigate this problem on Google, and have already spent several weeks to months trying to fix it. Errors I get in the event viewer are the following:

> TCP/IP failed to establish an outgoing connection because the selected
>   local endpoint was recently used to connect to the same remote
>   endpoint. This error typically occurs when outgoing connections are
>   opened and closed at a high rate, causing all available local ports to
>   be used and forcing TCP/IP to reuse a local port for an outgoing
>   connection. To minimize the risk of data corruption, the TCP/IP
>   standard requires a minimum time period to elapse between successive
>   connections from a given local endpoint to a given remote endpoint.

And

> A request to allocate an ephemeral port number from the global TCP port space has failed due to all such ports being in use.

I tried resetting the winsock and firewall but it does not have any effect ([Link](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6653)). I am also getting Access Denied even though I'm the administrator when running `netsh int ip reset reset.txt`. Error log:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh int ip reset reset.php
Resetting Compartment Forwarding, OK!
Resetting Compartment, OK!
Resetting Control Protocol, OK!
Resetting Echo Sequence Request, OK!
Resetting Global, OK!
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting Anycast Address, OK!
Resetting Multicast Address, OK!
Resetting Unicast Address, OK!
Resetting Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Path, OK!
Resetting Potential, OK!
Resetting Prefix Policy, OK!
Resetting Proxy Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Route, OK!
Resetting Site Prefix, OK!
Resetting Subinterface, OK!
Resetting Wakeup Pattern, OK!
Resetting Resolve Neighbor, OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.
```

I have tried to see if it was a problem with the home network, but quickly came to the conclusion that that was not the problem, as all devices work normally and this bug also affects my LocalHost.

It affects both cable and WiFi. Webpages sometimes do not load with `ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED`, and after about a 10 minutes it will randomly load (Not all webpages). Current connections like for example voice communications still work (E.g. Discord), but will eventually not work after switching from server for example. My taskbar (well Explorer.exe) also sometimes refreshes randomly

I have tried resetting the network, the firewall, using other WiFi USB sticks, changing IP, changing DNS, but nothing seems to work. I would not like to reset my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My internet connections sometimes drops randomly

Try **completely** reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I have already tried the first four with no result. I will try to do this whole riddle again, including the last two. Thank you, I will let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Hi, It eventualy happened again.. do you have any other option I can try?

Comment: @MarkD Unfortunately not :/